# page numbers at top right

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I've got a simple question, I think.  But I can't seem to find the answer to it anywhere.  I want page numbers at the top right of each page of my document.  How do I do this?

I tried doing:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

My text.

\end{document}
```

While this did result in page numbers being at the top right, I don't like the horizontal lines across the top of each page that this produces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` for example to set the head rule with to zero -- it won't appear then. The same can be applied to `\footrulewidth`, if necessary.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

My text.

\end{document}
```

[image]