# Set page number to top right

Tags: lyx

can anyone answer my question in details how to put page numbers on top right of my report, but I want the first pages (abstract, introduction,table of contents) to be numbered in roman numerals and in the button, I dont know how to use latex, i am using lyx and can only use buttons, if this need coding please tell me how in details.

Comment: It would be easier to hep you if  added [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). In particular, you need to give your documnent class as this affects the answer. Mind you, a quick on TeX.SX will probably give you the answer. See, for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233737/page-numbers-at-top-right.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_Page_Headers_and_Footers

Comment: You will need to learn the LaTeX basics, otherwise you will experience a lot of frustration.